# A question about `pd.Series.str` method when the series contains number

Tags: python, pandas

I spent quite a few minutes debugging a ETL process, and finally I found the following behavior when using `pd.Series.str`. Just wondering why `.str` method does not cast other type to str.

```
d = pd.Series((1,2,'A'))
d.str.lower()
```

produces

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2      a
```

BTW. the workaround here is to use `.apply(str)` to explicitly cast the original dtype to str.

Comment: You'd have to do `d.astype(str).str.lower()` to work, besides because you have mixed dtypes and have not explicitly cast the `dtype` it returns `NaN` where it cannot call `lower`, this is expected behaviour

Comment: [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html#accessors) . The `str` accessor is dtype-specific.If  your numbers are of the `np.int64` type, it won't work. Still, interesting to know that they're cast as np.nan automatically

Comment: @kerwei Great! Thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

The way str.lower() works is that it takes in a **string** and will return a **string** with lower-case letters, and any characters in the string that are not letters will not be changed.

In your code, the numbers 1 and 2 are input as integers, not strings, which is why they become NA after you call the lower-case method. Use quote marks if you'd like to precise that they're strings.

Why does it only work with strings? I believe you simply cannot have upper-case or lower-case numbers or special characters. It is just a matter of standardization.

The lower-casing algorithm is described in section 3.13 of the Unicode Standard. I invite you to get a hold of it if you'd want a deeper understanding.

Comment: I do not know `.str` is dtype-specific. If `.str` can cast dtype to `str`, `.lower` should work too. You can see the comment from @kerwei